# Rails validate field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have followin the http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

```
class User < ActiveRecord
  attr_accessible ..., :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  validates :password, :presence => true,
                       :length => { :minimum => 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, :presence => true

  ....
end
```

the problem is to create a new user this works fine, both passwords must be present and they need to match, when i update it requires me to provide the password

for example if another controller wants to change any field of User i must provide a password because otherwise i will not be able to update.

how can i formulate a contition to only require password/password_confirmation when creating the model or doing password update ?

Comment: Don't show the password and password confirmation fields on the edit form.

Comment: the problem i want change fields in another controller with no edit form, for example in the console
user1 = User.first
user1.field1 = "hi"
user1.save
this would leave a error password / password_confirmation cant be blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using rails3, you can [skip validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html). From the docs:

> The following methods skip validations, and will save the object to
>   the database regardless of its validity. They should be used with
>   caution.
>
> - decrement!
> - decrement_counter
> - increment!
> - increment_counter
> - toggle!
> - touch
> - update_all
> - update_attribute
> - update_column
> - update_counters
>
> Note that save also has the ability to skip validations if passed `:validate => false` as argument. This technique should be used with caution.

Basically, use `find` to find the appropriate user, update whatever fields you want, `user.save!(:validate=>false)`, and Bob's your uncle!

Comment: Why would you want to skip validations on user input? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of having validations to begin with?

Comment: @ChrisPeters you skip validations if, like the OP, you are updating the model and don't want to bother with the validations.

Comment: "Not bothering with validations" is the lazy way out and can cause data integrity issues. What if the user decides to leave a required field blank? They'll either generate invalid data or cause a SQL error, depending on whether or not `NOT NULL` constraints are placed on the underlying column.

Comment: @ChrisPeters you know what you should do then? Vote down the question, not my answer to it. OP specifically said **how can i formulate a contition to only require password/password_confirmation when creating the model or doing password update?** In other words, he wants validations *disabled* on create and update.

Answer (score 1):

Rails supports conditional validations, e.g. in your User model

```
validates :password_confirmation, :presence => true, :if => :new_password

def new_password
  current_user and current_user.changing_password?
end
```

You would need to figure out in the `new_password` method how to tell whatever conditions are true when you want to validate.

See: http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations